# add a condition if none of the elements in a for loop has data

Tags: python

I have a for loop, which read a directory content and retrieve `.log` files.

```
for logs in glob.glob('*.log'):
    # do something
```

But sometimes the folder has no log files, so nothing happen. I could add an `if` statement to check every cycle of the for loop, if the value of `logs` is not `None`, although it feels like it is not the right way to do it in Python.

Is there a more efficient way that is more close to the Python way to do this? The objective is to have a condition where if none of the cycles of the loop has returned any log file, then I should handle that giving a meaningful message via print, or triggering some other function. Thanks.

Comment: `although it feels like it is not the right way to do it in Python.` why do you say that ?

Comment: If the folder has no log files, you're not going to get `logs = None` in the loop, you're just not going to get the loop run at all.

Comment: The problem with the if inside the loop is mostly for a form perspective; I can add it, although I would not like to give the impression that I do not know what I am doing :)

Comment: When there are no log files nothing happen; I would like to print something, since I may call this function from another function, and end up not having any output. Another thing I did think is to wrap in a Try block, but that would not change much my situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
files_to_process =glob.glob('*.log')
if not files_to_process:
    # call a funtion
```

Comment: Just do `if not files_to_process:`, don't call `len` just to compare it to 0 in Python.

Comment: I see, you are calling the glob and in place, checking. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a misconception here:

> But sometimes the folder has no log files, so nothing happen. I could add an if statement to check every cycle of the for loop, if the value of `logs` is not `None`…

That won't do anything. If there are no logs, the `glob` will return an empty list, and that won't run your loop with `logs=None`, it just won't run your loop at all:

```
>>> files = []
>>> for file in files:
...     if file is None:
...         print('None')
...     else:
...         print(file)
```

This will print nothing at all.

If you want to test whether there were any results, the simplest thing to do is just test the results:

```
files = glob.glob('*.log')
for file in files:
    # do something
if not files:
    print('No files')
```

---

This isn't a fully general solution, if the iterable you're looping over could be an iterator rather than a sequence or other container. A sequence is truthy if and only if it's non-empty, but an iterator is always truthy. Plus, there's no way to check whether an iterator is empty except by iterating it. So, the general solution, that works even with iterators, requires some kind of flag or counter.

Sometimes a hacky solution like this is readable enough:

```
file = None
for file in glob.glob('*.log'):
    # do something
if file is not None:
    print('Empty')
```

… but I think in many cases (where the loop isn't so trivial that you can immediately connect the `file = None` above it to the test after it, or where you can't use `None` because it's a valid value for the iterable, etc.), you're better off being explicit.

Or, if you know that you're getting a sequence, as you do with `glob`, just do the simple `if not seq:` test described above.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive post. I did not express myself clearly then, since I am aware that nothing happen, but I cannot do something, if I don't put a condition (no files returned from the glob), which is why I was looking for a way to "mark" the fact that there may be nothing returned, and print something that point out that there are no log files. It could be because who use the function did not pass a right path; or something else went wrong...that's why I want to check, and after trying to use a nested IF, I thought that maybe was not the best way to do it.